# rails server エラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails で開発をしています。

rails serverで起動させようとしたところ、エラーが出ました。
どのように解決すればよいでしょうか？
回答いただけますと幸いです。

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.5 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/ITABASHIYUKI/Desktop/baukis/config/routes.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `delate' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fadbde88cb8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean? delete
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:935:in `block (2 levels) in namespace'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:866:in `scope'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:935:in `block in namespace'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1820:in `path_scope'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:934:in `namespace'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1546:in `namespace'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/Desktop/baukis/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `eval_block'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:418:in `draw'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/Desktop/baukis/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-
```

以下、文字数の都合上 略

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13187028913

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> /Users/ITABASHIYUKI/Desktop/baukis/config/routes.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `delate' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fadbde88cb8> (NoMethodError)
> Did you mean? delete
> ```

エラーメッセージの通りです。config/routes.rbの７行目に書かれている`delate`がスペルミスです。